# Why TypesScript allows an invalid comparison - boolean === undefined?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-typings, tslint

Faced with the strange behavior of TS.

```
const isItLanding = false;

if (isItLanding === undefined) { // valid
  return ...;
}
```

But here

```
const isItLanding = 1;

if (isItLanding === 'undefined') { // error
  return ...;
}
```

Why doesn't TS insure against writing invalid comparisons? And how can I change this behavior?

My TS config looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strict": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": ".next/cache/.tscache/",
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["src/*"],
      "test-utils": ["./src/client/test-utils"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "cypress"]
}
```

Comment: What does your tsconfig look like? You probably don't have some strict setting enabled.

Comment: whether strict setting is enabled or not, he should not get the first two results as valid. or is that possible?

Comment: Whether or not the comparison is permitted has no effect on type safety in these cases. The compiler still narrows the type of the value to `never` in the resulting truthy code branch: https://tsplay.dev/w17jGm

Comment: @jsejcksn Looks very bad, and there is no solution?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74531991/why-typesscript-allows-an-invalid-comparison-boolean-undefined?noredirect=1#comment131566395_74531991) @coolswood If you don't want to permit certain syntax in your code, that's the job of a linter. There's no type safety issue here.

Comment: @jsejcksn I can't tell the difference. Comparison of a string and a number TS considers an error, but the case with undefined - no? It looks like a flaw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the right rule in the linter at https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unnecessary-condition.
This completely solves the problem!

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer: TypeScript intentionally allows any type to be compared to "null" or "undefined"**

## It is allowed because boolean can be undefined

In TypeScript boolean can hold four values `true`, `false`, `undefined` and `null`, what means that by definition there might be a case where the comparison will in fact be true.

```js
let bool: boolean = true;
bool = false;
bool = null;
bool = undefined;
//All compiles without an issue

if(bool === undefined){
   console.log("You will see me!");
}
```

### How to ensure that boolean can only be true or false?

In your TS config you can set a flag `strictNullChecks` to `true`, this way when type is checked both `undefined` and `null` will be taken into account.
Once this flag is set, the code above will return an error.

```js
let bool: boolean = true;
bool = false;
bool = null; //Error > Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
bool = undefined; //Error > Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

### Why after changing the flag comparison to null or undefined is still allowed?

Consider the code below:

```js
const bool: boolean = false;

if(bool === undefined){
   console.log("I am undefined!");
}
if(bool === null){
   console.log("I am null!");
}

console.log("It compiled?");
```

##### Why neither of these if statements return an error, even if they are always false?

The answer might be disappointing to some, but the reason is simple: **It is intentionally designed that you can compare any type to "null" or "undefined"**. It's the way the language was constructed, that is to allow defensive programming. It might be changed in the future, if there is enough of demand, but I personally don't think there ever will be.

```js
if(12 === undefined){
   console.log("impossible isn't it?");
}
if("ab" === null){
   console.log("no way it will ever be true!");
}
if(false === undefined){
   console.log("never ever");
}

/*
if(12 === "ab") 
^this would error as comparison to different types is allowed only with null and undefined
*/

console.log("Yet, it will indeed compile");
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! In case anyone reading is looking for some official references like me... https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14764 https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11920

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is intentional. See discussions about it at [#14764](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14764) or [#11920](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11920).

---

In short: Checking if something is `undefined` or `null` is needed for the sake of *"defensive programming"*.

One should be able to test inputs to be valid to when values might be coming from non-TypeScript users.

Consider a function like this:

```
function fn(x: string) {
  if (x === undefined) throw new Error('x cannot be undefined');
}
```

Its entirely possible that someone using JavaScript would call this function with a value that might be `undefined`. Having a compile time error disallowing the comparison would be annoying.

Comment: I don't agree with you. If you mix Typescript with js, you should honestly define the interface. In your example x should be string | undefined or any.

Comment: @coolswood - if you write any library, you can't possible know if your users are gonna use TypeScript or JavaScript. Declaring `x` as `string | undefined` would falsely convey that the function accepts `undefined`, which it does not.